# How much pressure does a balloon exert on the gas inside it?

Tags: pressure

In most calculations in physics classes I've seen, the pressure of the actual latex as it expands is neglected, and the pressure of the air inside the balloon is assumed to be atmospheric pressure. What would the actual pressure difference between the air in a balloon and the surrounding air be?

Comment: I don't think you've read those solutions correctly.  Give us a real quotation, because what you state here is impossible.  If the pressure inside the balloon is atmospheric pressure, the balloon is deflated.

Comment: In the comment case the baloon is deflated right because of its tension. An overpressure - however small - is needed to inflate it

Comment: I believe what he means is that physics problems in a textbook or the like often assume equal pressure inside and out because they are quite similar. He is asking how much pressure difference there really is in real life.

Answer (score 1):

It is very little. You can easily test this by having it deflate through a tube with its opening under water. Generally about one foot of water will be enough to stop the air flow.